# How to create a Right click drop down menu for GWT cell table

Tags: gwt, contextmenu, celltable

I have a cell table in GWT. I need to create a Right click on the rows in the Cell table. I have tried various methods but it isn't working. Can someone please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Cell Tree Right Click Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599619/gwt-cell-tree-right-click-selection)

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate. The OP wants a row-level event, not a cell-level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
myTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<MyObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<MyObject> event) {
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT) {
            event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();
            // do something instead with myObject (event.getValue()) or
            // with this row (event.getIndex())
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I have minimum knowledge on GWT. Could you please elaborate how can I add values to the list that should be populated when I click the right click. I am looking for something like contextmenu on a row click.

Comment: You can show your own popup panel or something on the right click, and then act based on a user selection. But I cannot answer your question about adding values (which values?) to a list (which list?) without knowing more about your requirements. It probably deserves a separate question.

Comment: I am trying to create a dropdown panel on the right click on the row. The Dropdown is like a context menu which will have a few fields: Create , Delete, Submit etc. I am using              MenuBar options = new MenuBar();  options.addItem("Create", gwtPop);
options.addItem("Submit", gwtPop);